# root.update is lagging in linux but not windows

Tags: python, tkinter

My python tkinter code is lagging severely in linux but not windows. It has something to do with root.update() and root.config(). How do I fix this so that the linux version is just as fast as the windows version?

I've written a python program on windows which works well. I'm currently making a linux version. After some modification the linux version works as it should, except massive lagging. I inserted code to time different parts of the program. There are large differences from windows to linux for the `root.update()` and `root.config()` lines.

The following lines are the ones causing the lagging:

```
root.update()
root.config(menu=menubar)
```

I ran the program several times in windows and linux and recorded the amount of time used to execute the code.

The following is a record of the run times for the lines:

In windows:

```
root update:  0.47  seconds 
root update:  0.2656  seconds
root update:  0.3125  seconds
root update:  0.3594  second
root update:  0.3593  seconds
menubar root config done:  0.0081
menubar root config done:  0.0
```

In windows: Process finished with exit code `-1`

pycharm in windows is using Python 3.7

---

In linux:

```
root update:  2.4416  seconds
root update:  87.3216  seconds
root update:  1.5798  seconds
root update:  148.2783  seconds
root update:  2.2533  seconds
root update:  2.2771  seconds
root update:  2.4898  seconds
root update:  8.022  seconds
root update:  171.6852  seconds
root update:  1.7088  seconds
menubar root config done:  0.0441
menubar root config done:  2.4566
menubar root config done:  1.2589
```

In linux: Process finished with exit code `9`

pycharm in linux is using Python 3.6

Here is the code as simple as I can make it. There is a gui made by tkinter, queries to a mysql database, a function which generates a menubar and lots of widgets put in a grid.

```
root = Tk()
root.title("KLUSTERBOX")

...

def main_frame(): # call function to make the main screen

# define and put widgets on a grid

...

generate_menubar(Frame) # call function to make menubar

# define the menubar

root.config(menu=menubar)

...

# define and put widgets on a grid

root.update()
```

I was asked for a MCVE. This is a sample program which duplicates the problem:

```
from tkinter import *
import time
import sys
def main_frame():
    starttime = time.time()
    F = Frame(root)
    F.pack(fill=BOTH, side=LEFT)
    C1 = Canvas(F)
    C1.pack(fill=BOTH, side=BOTTOM)
    Button(C1, text="Refresh", width=12, command=lambda: [F.destroy(),main_frame()]).pack(side=LEFT)
    Button(C1, text="Quit", width=12, command=root.destroy).pack(side=LEFT)
    # link up the canvas and scrollbar
    S = Scrollbar(F)
    C = Canvas(F, width=1600)
    S.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=BOTH)
    C.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, pady=10, padx=10)
    S.configure(command=C.yview, orient="vertical")
    C.configure(yscrollcommand=S.set)
    if sys.platform == "win32":
        C.bind_all('<MouseWheel>', lambda event: C.yview_scroll(int(-1 * (event.delta / 120)), "units"))
    elif sys.platform == "linux":
        C.bind_all('<Button-4>', lambda event: C.yview('scroll',-1,'units'))
        C.bind_all('<Button-5>', lambda event: C.yview('scroll',1,'units'))
    # create the frame inside the canvas
    preF=Frame(C)
    C.create_window((0, 0), window=preF, anchor=NW)
    Label(preF, text="To refresh - press REFRESH").pack()
    Label(preF, text="To quit - press QUIT").pack()
    Label(preF, text="Run times are displayed in console").pack()
    FF = Frame(C)
    C.create_window((0,108), window=FF, anchor=NW)
    for i in range(100):
        Button(FF, text=i, width=5, bg="yellow", anchor="w").grid(row=i,column=0)
        Button(FF, text="hello there", width=24, bg="yellow", anchor="w").grid(row=i,column=1)
        Button(FF, text=" ", width=5, bg="green", anchor="w").grid(row=i, column=2)
        Button(FF, text=" ", width=5, bg="green", anchor="w").grid(row=i,column=3)
        Button(FF, text=" ", width=5, bg="green", anchor="w").grid(row=i, column=4)
        Button(FF, text=" ", width=5, bg="green", anchor="w").grid(row=i, column=5)
    endtime = time.time()
    print("runtime prior to root.update(): ", round(endtime - starttime,4), " seconds")
    starttime = time.time()
    root.update()
    endtime = time.time()
    print("root.update() runtime: ", round(endtime-starttime,4)," seconds")
    C.config(scrollregion=C.bbox("all"))
    mainloop()
root = Tk()
root.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (625,600,100,50))
main_frame()
```

I have timed the run times for the `root.update()` and `root.config(menu=menubar)`. The times in linux are too long and would make the program unusable, especially considering that there are other part of the program which lag much more.

Comment: use button `{}` to correctly format code.

Comment: Please create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with an focus an the C and V. Your code is not enough to reproduce the problem.

Comment: many other programs run in systems. In different systems runs different number of programs. Your program have to share CPU with them. Python code looks the same on both systems but they may use different libraries to display it - different system have different methods/API for GUI. Usually programs don't need `root.update()`

Comment: Does it work any faster if you use `root.update_idletasks()` instead?  That's a lot safer than `.update()`, and is all you need to get valid geometry so that you can set your scrollregion correctly.

Comment: @jasonharper I tried that. It didn't work. The runtime was not effected for better or worse. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: @KlausD. Ok, I created a sample program which duplicates the problem. The code is included above.

Comment: @furas  Thanks for the explanation. I didn't know that. Do you have any idea of how I could get around using root.update()? Someone else suggested .update_idletask(). That didn't work.

Comment: On my Linux Mint `root.update` takes only 0.3s - tested with Python 3.7, 3.6, 2.7. If I destroy only `FF` and create it again (without running `main_frame()` again) then refresh takes 0.08s. Other elements don't change so there is no need to remove them and create again.

Answer (score 1):

On my Linux Mint it takes 0.3s (Python 3.7, 3.6, 2.7) and I don't know why it runs so slow on your Linux.

Here is only code with some changes - maybe it will help.

- I don't use `root.update()` but `after()` to change `scrollregion` 100ms after starting `mainloop()`. Before running `mainloop()` all widgets don't exist yet and it can't calculate `scrollregion`.
- I don't destroy `F` with all widgets but I destroy only frame with buttons which creates table and I recreate only this frame.
- I don't run `main_frame` again so I don't run another `mainloop()`
- I had to use `global` to keep access to frame with table because `command=` can't get value from function and assing to variable.

Start takes 0.3s and refresh takes 0.09s

.

```
from tkinter import *
import time
import sys

def create_table(C):
    table = Frame(C)

    C.create_window((0,108), window=table, anchor=NW)

    for i in range(100):
        Button(table, text=i, width=5, bg="yellow", anchor="w").grid(row=i,column=0)
        Button(table, text="hello there" + str(X), width=24, bg="yellow", anchor="w").grid(row=i,column=1)
        Button(table, text=" ", width=5, bg="green", anchor="w").grid(row=i, column=2)
        Button(table, text=" ", width=5, bg="green", anchor="w").grid(row=i,column=3)
        Button(table, text=" ", width=5, bg="green", anchor="w").grid(row=i, column=4)
        Button(table, text=" ", width=5, bg="green", anchor="w").grid(row=i, column=5)

    return table
    
def refresh(C):
    global table

    starttime = time.time()

    table.destroy()
    table = create_table(C)

    endtime = time.time()

    print("refresh: ", round(endtime-starttime,4)," seconds")

    
def main_frame():
    global table

    starttime = time.time()

    F = Frame(root)
    F.pack(fill=BOTH, side=LEFT)

    C1 = Canvas(F)
    C1.pack(fill=BOTH, side=BOTTOM)

    Button(C1, text="Refresh", width=12, command=lambda:refresh(C)).pack(side=LEFT)
    Button(C1, text="Quit", width=12, command=root.destroy).pack(side=LEFT)

    # link up the canvas and scrollbar
    S = Scrollbar(F)
    C = Canvas(F, width=1600)
    S.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=BOTH)
    C.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, pady=10, padx=10)
    S.configure(command=C.yview, orient="vertical")
    C.configure(yscrollcommand=S.set)

    if sys.platform == "win32":
        C.bind_all('<MouseWheel>', lambda event: C.yview_scroll(int(-1 * (event.delta / 120)), "units"))
    elif sys.platform == "linux":
        C.bind_all('<Button-4>', lambda event: C.yview('scroll',-1,'units'))
        C.bind_all('<Button-5>', lambda event: C.yview('scroll',1,'units'))

    # create the frame inside the canvas
    preF=Frame(C)
    C.create_window((0, 0), window=preF, anchor=NW)
    Label(preF, text="To refresh - press REFRESH").pack()
    Label(preF, text="To quit - press QUIT").pack()
    Label(preF, text="Run times are displayed in console").pack()
    
    table = create_table(C)
    
    endtime = time.time()
    print("runtime: ", round(endtime - starttime,4), " seconds")
    
    # update scrollregion 100ms after mainloop start
    root.after(100, lambda:C.config(scrollregion=C.bbox("all")))
    mainloop()
    
    
root = Tk()
root.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (625,600,100,50))
main_frame()
```

Comment: Thanks so much for you effort. I copy/pasted your code into pycharm and ran it. It ran flawlessly in Windows, but still super slow in Linux. I'm thinking there must be a problem with either my python libraries in Linux or the OS itself. I'll try to reinstall python on Linux, if that doesn't work I'll switch over to Mint. I'm using Ubuntu right now.

Comment: Did you run it without PyCharm ? It rather shouldn't make difference but who knows.

Comment: I did run it in terminal with the same problem. I cleaned Ubuntu off my hard drive, installed Linux Mint and the problem is solved.

Comment: interesting - I would expect the same speed. Linix Mint (19.1) is built on top of Ubuntu (18.04) - but it uses different Desktop Environment and/or Windows Manager.

Comment: huh. I didn't know that. All I did was to install a couple libraries in pip (just openpyxl and Pillow). Other than that, it was a fresh install of Ubuntu. Maybe a glitch.